# Change the rows and columns and rename the columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I want to transpose the rows and columns and change the name of columns as follow. My dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['time'] = [1,2,3,4]
df ['a'] = [3,-1,0, 23]
df['b'] = [-1, 2, 5, 6]
df
```

I want to change it to the following:

[image]

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Try `df.T` ??  Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Transpose and rename would be what you want as this code.

```
df.T.rename(columns={0:'val 0', 1:'val 1', 2:'val 2', 3:'val 3'}, index={'time':0, 'a':1, 'b':2})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual way to insert the columns and indexes' names.

```
header = ["val_0", "val_2", "val_3", "val_4"]
index = range(len(df.columns))

df=df.T
df.columns=header
df.index=index
df

   val_0  val_2  val_3  val_4
0      1      2      3      4
1      3     -1      0     23
2     -1      2      5      6
```